# How do you highlight typed text when it's not static?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Example of what I'm going for.

I have two Textareas. One holds a list of single words, one per line, this list will not be the same every time.

My second text area will be used for input by the user. My goal is to highlight words in the first text area when that word is typed into the second text area. I've attached an example photo showing what I wish to accomplish.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ia36.jpg

My code is just pushing a list of words into the first Text area and separating them. I'm looking for help on how to highlight the desired words.

```
<textarea class="col-md-3" id="inputArray1" rows="20" cols="10" placeholder="Input1"></textarea>
<textarea class="col-md-3" id="inputArray2" rows="20" cols="10" placeholder="Input2"></textarea>

//holding input values for text area
var InputVar = document.getElementById("inputArray1").value;
var InputVar2 = document.getElementById("inputArray2").value;

//holding output values for text area
var OutputVar = document.getElementById("outputArray1");
var OutputVar2 = document.getElementById("outputArray2");

// takes string and breaks into substring array of words
var SplitString = InputVar.split(/[\s]+/g);

//displays list of words in 2nd text area
OutputVar.value = SplitString;
```

Comment: You cannot highlight text inside `textarea`. Would it be possible to use a normal `div` with a list of words wrapped inside `<span>`s?

Comment: The list of words has to be pushed from a string/array that the user will have entered prior. as long as I can pass that info into a div that would be fine. main goal is just to highlight the words that are being displayed.

Comment: does case-sensitivity matter?

Comment: It would be ideal to have lower case and upper case be able to be highlighted, using a regex or something to highlight capitalized words won't cut it unfortunately.

Comment: Use a contenteditable div with [mark.js](https://markjs.io/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you tagged jQuery, here is a basic function that checks if any user words match any of the listed words:

```js
$("#userArray").on('change keyup paste', function() {
  var input = $(this).val().split("\n");
  $('#listArray span').each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    if ($.inArray($(this).text(), input) != -1) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#list_input > div { border:4px solid; padding: 1em; margin: 1em auto; }
#listArray { overflow: auto; }
#listArray span { display: block; float: left; clear: left; padding:4px; margin:1px; }
#listArray span.active { background: yellow; }
#userArray { width: 100%; height: 150px; border: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="list_input">
  <div id="listArray">
    <span>Lorem</span>
    <span>Eos</span>
    <span>Earum</span>
    <span>Tempora</span>
    <span>Recusandae</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <textarea id="userArray" placeholder="enter words..."></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/3x3ga3tL/

---

**Edit:** you can append a list of words dynamically from a JS array using the following script:

```
var words = ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3","Test4"];
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    $('#listArray').append("<span>" + words[i] + "</span>");
}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/3x3ga3tL/6/

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Is there a way to make it case sensitive. Also when the words are removed they still stay highlighted, so i'd have to make some kind of update to check the current status?

Comment: @Pyreal oh I forgot about this. I've added case-insensitivity and class reset when the word is removed.

Comment: @Pyreal I thought you said you needed two textareas that won't be the same? Or is user input only needed on one end?

Comment: Thanks, seems to work perfectly when words are removed. Still highlighting regardless if typed word is lowercase or uppercase.

Comment: @Pyreal you want it to highlight when the case is exact?

Comment: @Zach One textarea will be a list of words. it doesn't necessarily have to be a textarea but it has to be able to hold multiple lines of text. The second has to be able to take input from the user and highlight words in the first when typed like Aziz example.

Comment: @Aziz That's Correct, I'd like it to take case into account.

Comment: @Aziz is it possible to push an array of words into individual spans? seems like the spans have to be matched exactly to work correctly.

varArray = ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3","Test4"]

then push each one into a span with a loop or something?

Comment: @Pyreal sure, you can use a `for` loop to append each word in the array. see updated answer.